Need for Gazebo plugins and SDF tutorial
I am just beginning to work with Gazebo. I need to create drones models with autotesting and plugins that will communicate with firmware. Also I plan to use genetic algorithm for AI based drones developments, i. e. I will need to get drone state in fully automatic maneer and I will use machine learning for increasing model quality depending on different wheather and environment.
So, it looks that I will need to understand in deep its plugins system. Good news for me is that I am C++ programmer.
But I can not find appopriate documentation for the latest Gazebo (Gazebo Harmonics) version. I can not find neither tutorial nor documentation. There is some information for the Gazebo Classic version, but I would prefere to use the latest LTS version.
Also it looks that I have to master SDF models creation.
Could you suggest me appropriate information about those topics?

I'm curious to know where you looked for tutorials. Were you able to find https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/tutorials.html?

For sim tutorials are probably good, but for plugins they are too brief : https://gazebosim.org/api/plugin/2/tutorials.html .
I would like to find some genereal tutorials, not for each component individually, but for full system.

The documentation and tutorials are very brief.
Working with SDF the following are very useful:

SDFormat Specification
Gazebo docs - SDF worlds

The official tutorials for Gazebo Sim can be found here:

Gazebo docs - Tutorials
Gazebo API tutorials
Gazebo API tutorials - Create System plugins

Setting up plugins myself was quite challenging with just these tutorials. What really helped me was reading through the code of gz-sim and packages found in the Gazebo Community.

gz-sim Git - System plugins
gz-sim Git - Examples plugins
Community plugin Git - Waste Bin

These combined with the Gazebo tutorials should get you started since you have C++ experience.

Here is a link to the Gazebo Harmonics tutorial about SDF worlds and plugins:
https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/sdf_worlds
And here is some documentation on the gazebo plugins: https://gazebosim.org/api/plugin/2/index.html . However, for someone new to Gazebo, I would recommend checking out the tutorial first.
Here is also a link to a youtube video of the sdf tutorial. The tutorial is for the previous LTS version of Gazebo Sim, gazebo ignition, but the video is still applicable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48TX-XJ14Gs
Hope this helps and best of luck learning Gazebo!
